# Azure SignalR Service

Tags: azure, signalr, signalr-hub

There is very limited information on azure signalR service. I need to clarify a question so any help would be highly appreciated.
how azure signalR service actually scale out ? I mean, as far I have worked on it. it seems that you have to include a primary key of azure signalR service to your hub. you can host you hub anywhere. So how hub scales out.?

Comment: I have created a simple chat app in .net core. have created Azure signalR service. have added the Azure SignalR Service connection string in signalR hub. it is working fine on my local environment. I can see the total connection and message rate on my azure portal. so its working fine but need to clarify that how scaling out will actually happen on stress situation.

Comment: you can ask me a question if you need any further clarification on question. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

SignalR Service manages all the client connections, as well as certain state information such as group membership. Your ASP.NET Core application establishes a connection to the SignalR Service instance.

When the application wants to send a message to connected clients, it uses this connection to instruct the service to do so. The service can also invoke hub methods via this connection.

You can read more about the [service protocol](https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/blob/dev/specs/ServiceProtocol.md).

When a client initiates a connection, it calls a negotiate endpoint on your ASP.NET Core application, which redirects the client to connect to the SignalR Service instance instead.

Because the ASP.NET Core application only needs to execute hub logic and most of the heavy lifting is done by SignalR Service, your application does not typically have to scale out to handle more SignalR connections. You can scale it based on the needs of the web traffic (serving web API and MVC requests, for example), and you can scale the service based on the needs of your SignalR traffic.

Comment: PS - I work at Microsoft. The service is currently in public preview and we're working hard on adding more documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your response and link to documentation. it was very helpful. I have build and deployed a simple chat app using AzuresignalR service on Azure webapp but I am not getting the right connection count and other matrices data on azure portal. which I really need if I have to use this service in real scenario. please open the link for more detail about this issue. Any help would be great. Thanks 
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlvUGtjUbWEaiSs-E1OZJy_Ctr4q.

Comment: Can you clarify the part about the connection breaking? Did you implement any reconnect logic? Sometimes websocket connections are interrupted and you need to reconnect. SignalR does not reconnect for you, you have to implement this logic yourself.

Comment: No I haven't implemented reconnect logic. Thought that it will be handled my signalR itself.

Comment: ASP.NET SignalR clients had reconnect logic built in. Clients for the newer ASP.NET Core SignalR that you're using do not. You need to implement it based on your needs. You can simply call start on the connection again to reconnect.

Comment: Will write a proper brief blog and demo on this ASAP. it need documentation badly. will need you help for this.

Comment: If you use SignalR service, there will be both server and client connecting to the service. So the 6 connections you saw on the portal actually consists of 5 server connections and 1 client connection (the default number of server connections is 5 per server). We're going to separate them into two metrics to make them more clear.

Comment: Regarding hub scale out, you can have multiple servers hosting the same hub (use whatever technology you like) and connecting to the same service instance. When a client is connected, service will route the client connection to one server connection. Next time the client sends a message, it will always be routed to the same server connection, so every time only one hub server will get the message.

Comment: should't it be one to one connection and if it so what other four connections exactly do.On the other hand, I have added a counter variable in hub, which show right count for every client connects or disconnects.

Comment: You can change it from 5 to 1 if you want. It'll reduce the throughout though

Comment: so if a .net core app is using the azure signalR service, it would mean there is no web sockets running on the .net core app?

Answer (score 1):

This is the documentation that I found and followed to have a signalr hub that worked across multiple App Service instances but behaving as a single hub.

You need to create a "backplane" in Azure using Storage queues and topics.

Details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-windows-azure-service-bus

@anthonychu is this still needed / applicable??

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have implemented that as well. but according to Microsoft, Azure signalR service is more prefer over this. So I am implementing Azure SingalR Service now.

Comment: There are 2 versions of SignalR. The Service Bus backplane is only applicable to the "original" SignalR (aka ASP.NET SignalR). The "newer" SignalR (ASP.NET Core SignalR) that @UsmanJaved is using does support a Redis backplane, but that's still more complicated to set up than simply using SignalR Service to scale out. We need to do a better job of distinguishing between the different versions of SignalR to avoid some of this confusion.

Comment: @AnthonyChu Quick question - do I have to do anything if I have a Web App using Azure SignalR scaled out with multiple server instances to make sure connections on different Web App servers all get updates? Thank you for your comments here, they help a lot!